# Google api auth client token for server api calls

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I want to integrate users google calendar with my web app. I have been looking through the google docs but at this stage it is not clear whether i can use the simple drop in java-script library Auth the user and use that Auth token on my server for simple API calls to the calendar API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check this [Google Calendar API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) for reference.

Every request your application sends to the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in), some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

After the initial user authorization, calls to `gapi.auth.authorize` that use `immediate:true` mode will obtain an auth token without user interaction.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So this means I can use the google java-script library to oAuth the user. Then use that token (credential) server side to post update calendar events